# Transfer function for a temperature sensor

Tags: sensor, temperature, transfer-function, linear

I have a STLM20 temperature sensor with the following transfer function:

$$V_{0}=\frac{-11.69\text{mV}}{C \cdot T} + 1.8663 \text{V}$$

I have solved it for \$T\$ and it should be:

$$T=85.543\cdot (1.8663-V_{0})$$

Is this correct?

Comment: It is correct and strictly speaking this is a math question - applied algebra.

Comment: Technically that's a scaling equation, not a transfer function.

Comment: @MattYoung I think this could accurately be described as the inverse transfer function of the sensor, since it gives degrees C as a function of volts.

Answer (score 1):

That's correct, and it's the best linear equation for the range 20°C< T <30°C, however you can get better accuracy over a wider range by using the quadratic solution:

[image]

According to the [data sheet](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00119601.pdf).